# issue installing PHP 7.1 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, php

I need to install PHP 7.1 in ubuntu 14.04. I try to do so by following the step by step instructions found online:

1. First add the repository:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

and everything seems to work correctly obtaining the following output:

```
 Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions 

are included. Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Debian oldstable and stable packages are provided as well: https://deb.sury.org/#debian-dpa

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

CAVEATS:
1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advise to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx

PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 Más información: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Pulse [Intro] para continuar o ctrl-c para cancelar

gpg: anillo «/tmp/tmpgtjszist/secring.gpg» creado
gpg: anillo «/tmp/tmpgtjszist/pubring.gpg» creado
gpg: solicitando clave E5267A6C de hkp servidor keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpgtjszist/trustdb.gpg: se ha creado base de datos de confianza
gpg: clave E5267A6C: clave pública "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" importada
gpg: Cantidad total procesada: 1
gpg:               importadas: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

2. I then do `sudo apt-get update` and notice that no mention is made of the ondrej repository.
3. I finally try to install php `sudo apt-get install php7.1` but it does not find the packages.

I have tried listing php relates packages available by executing `apt-cache search php7` but nothing is available, only php5 is.

I am desperate. I have noticed that when installing the repositories there is a warning mentioning that

> add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales

but even if I follow the instructions in the provided link nothing seems to change, because in fact my locale is es_ES.UTF-8.

```
$ locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu [14.04 has reached EOL](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2019/02/05/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) and consequently, the packages are no longer available in the PPA.

> Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Answer (score -1):

After upgrading the Ubuntu OS .. I was able to install the latest versions of PHP